# Proxy service likes Apache Http

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

Currently I try to simulate my app as distributed servers, so I let them run on localhost:9000 and localhost:9001, i tried using apache load balancer but it is really hard to config on mac, my idea is the second server localhost:9001 will be kept ideal and the requests only be redirected to them when the first server is downed. Is there any good free program can do that ? (except Apache httpd).

Extra functions: my application is written in java and maintain an in-memory object, is there any service that can synchronize that object between 2 servers so they can keep uptodate status of other (the second one takes state of the first one)? Is there any app can support that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Varnish is a good way to achieve load balancing. o I suggest you to have a look at it. [Here you can find the projects homepage](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)